# How to decide a resource in a restful way based on some tables

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to know how to decide what is a resource and what is a sub resource. I just have  some tables for which i need to make uri's. so lets say i have a student table and studentclass(which gives the name and probably some more details of the class that the student is enrolled in) table with (N:1).

I will make student a main resource and design uri like below

```
http://home/someapi/v1/student/1/
```

Following a rest approach for building uri

**Qus 1:** Which uri shown below do i have to make for accessing the studentclass

```
1.http://home/someapi/v1/studentclass?studentid=1 or
2.http://home/someapi/v1/student/1/studentclass
```

Do i have to consider studentclass as a separate resource..?

and

**Qus 2:** Suppose there is N:N relation between tables then how should the design of uri be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to deal with two resources: `student` and `class`.

You can get a `student` using the following URI:

```
http://home/someapi/v1/students/1
```

Note the plural here, read this article if you want to learn why you should use plural: http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_plural_nouns_and_concrete_names/.

If a `student` can be enrolled in one `class`, it **could** be a property of this student, so you could return the following JSON document (for example):

```
{
  "student": {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "class": {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Room Y"
    }
  }
}
```

You could get a specific `class` with the following URI:

```
http://home/someapi/v1/classes/10
```

You could get all students for a given class with this URI:

```
http://home/someapi/v1/classes/10/students
```

Now, if you have a **N-N** relation between `students` and `classes`, it would change my first proposal about the `student` representation in JSON. Actually, the `class` relation would become a collection of `class` resources, not an embedded property of a `student`, and you should use the following URI:

```
http://home/someapi/v1/students/1/classes
```

Meaning "retrieve all classes for student #1".

You can expose both `class` and `student` resources. No need to decide which one is the main one as they describe two different things. Having `/students` and `/classes` allows you to create `students` and `classes`, you can link them, etc.

Last thing, it's recommended to use query parameters (`?foo=bar`) for filtering purpose.

Comment: you mean to say the query parameters should be used as filters for the current resource that is requested..? Can you elaborate what should be present in query string parameters(in rest way)?

Comment: one more question can you support your statement that class becomes a propert of student if a student can be enrolled in one class

Comment: If you want to filter your resources by date or location, you should use the query string: `?location=foobar`.

Comment: For the "class" as property of the student, it's a suggestion. It's doable, depending on your needs (if you always need "class" information with a "student" for example).

Comment: can you give me some references which telling about identifying rest resources from database tables...? It would be helpful..Thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think StudentClass (or simply 'Class') should be a different resource as Class can be shared amoung students. So this Uri would suit your need:

http:home/someapi/v1/studentclass?studentid=1