# REST resources from database tables

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api

REST resources from database tables

I have recently learnt things about REST (many of them i partially understood). I also made some simple demos which are not very restful but atleast i have tried somethings of REST. But when it came to developing some real world applications starting from the scratch I am cluless.

My problem is

I have absolutely no idea, when a bunch of tables are given

1. how to start desigining uris out of them ?
2. how to decide what are the resources ...?
3. Can every table be a resource...?
4. how to tackle with one to many, many to many relations among those tables..?

All the questions above are confusing for me. Basically where to start with uri designing when a bunch of tables are thrown at your face for REST uri design! I know URI designing is not the only part that makes it REST API but still it is important one..

This question is a continuation to this one I posted earlier on SO
[How to decide a resource in a restful way based on some tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141237/how-to-decide-a-resource-in-a-restful-way-based-on-some-tables)

Please dont say that there is no such prescribed standard. There should be one :| . **I am asking only for a way ..just some direction where to start in designin uri's from db tables**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction).

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://rest.elkstein.org/) is a great REST tutorial. It has the REST architecture design and many samples.

Comment: Quick skimming, there are incorrect statements like "For creation, updating, and deleting data, use POST requests. (POST can also be used for read-only queries, as noted above, when complex parameters are required.)".

Comment: Oh yeah moomwave99! Good point! Can use the HTTP verbs like GET for read, POST for create/read complex, PUT for update and DELETE for delete.